# Diferencias entre las carpetas mipmap y drawable

Tags: android

He visto que en las dos carpetas se pueden almacenar recursos gráficos pero quisiera saber que diferencia habría entre las dos.

Comment: Hey David bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: David,  agrega más información a tu pregunta para que ayude a otros usuarios! , además puedes buscar información en el sitio.

Answer (score 3):

[`mipmap`](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) se utiliza cuando quieres cargar recursos dependiendo de la resolución del dispositivo, como por ejemplo el icono de la app. Si no diseñas el icono de la imagen en base a la resolución, puede que el icono lleve a verse mas pequeño de la cuenta en dispositivos con resoluciones altas o muy grande para resolucioens bajas. De hay que en el folder mipmap contenta folders como:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

Por lo que en cada folder debe de existir la misma imagen del icono solo que en base a su resolucion. Asi el sistema sabra cual recurso(icono) cargar segun la resolucion.

Mientras que `drawable` es para recursos generales que no dependerán de la resolución del dispositivo;

Comment: Nuevamente te pido nos ayudes a que los usuarios mejoren sus respuestas para responder. El iop puede preguntar en el [chat] para obtener información y realizar una respuesta que ayude a otros usuarios.

Comment: Jorge, no entendi. Porque el comentario?